# INSERT if not exists, UPDATE if exists, but only when certain condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure how to best solve this in the way I would like it to behave to my MYSQL database (via PHP).

Assuming we have a table with columns: id, name, city, status, last_modified, created_timestamp
id is the primary key.
created_timestmap has the attribute "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"

I want to insert into this table 100 values with a INSERT statement.
INSERT the row into the table when the record does not exist yet
UPDATE the row with id, name, city, last_modified when the record already exist. leave created_timestamp and status untouched. And only update the row when status = <specific value>

I have tried `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and `INSERT IGNORE` and `REPLACE` but they all are not meeting all requirements. This is what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, name, city, status, last_modified) VALUES <bunch of values> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), name=VALUES(name), city=VALUES(city), last_modified=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

- inserts row correctly. updates when already exists.
- I cannot give it the condition for status = <specific value>

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name (id, name, city, status, last_modified) VALUES <bunch of values>
```

- inserts row correctly. does not update existing records
- I cannot give it the condition for status = <specific value>

```
REPLACE INTO table_name (id, name, city, status, last_modified) VALUES <bunch of values>
```

- inserts row correctly
- when already exists, it deletes and re-creates the row which messes with created_timestamp
- I cannot give it the condition for status = <specific value>

What construct is best helpful to address my requirements?

Comment: Check conditional update if it fits your need https://thewebfellas.com/blog/conditional-duplicate-key-updates-with-mysql/

Comment: Is it the new value of `status` that should be checked, or the old value?

Comment: the old value of status

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `IF()` expressions in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause to make the updates conditional.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, name, city, status, last_modified) 
VALUES (<bunch of values>) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    id=IF(status = @value, VALUES(id), id), 
    name=IF(status = @value, VALUES(name), name), 
    city=IF(status = @value, VALUES(city), city),
    last_modified=IF(status = @value, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), last_modified)
```

`@value` represents the `<specific value>` you want to test.